# Passing C# struct to C++ unmanaged DLL returning incorrect result

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling

I have a simple C++ win32 DLL developed in visual studio 2017 and compiled in 64 bit environment having the following code:

```
typedef struct sum {
    struct  {
        int num1;
        int num2;
    } nums;
} sum1;

extern "C" {

__declspec(dllexport) int initialize(sum1 *summing)
{
    int res;
    res = summing->nums.num1 + summing->nums.num2;
    return res;
}

}
```

The above code contains a method which returns the sum of two integers by taking a typedef struct as an argument.

I have a C# client application which consumes this Win32 C++ DLL using PInvoke. Following is the code of my C# client application:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct nums
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct mydef
{
    public IntPtr sum;
}

public class LibWrap
{    
    [DllImport("C++.dll", EntryPoint = "initialize")]
    public static extern int Initialize(ref mydef mydef);
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        mydef mydef = new mydef();
        nums nums;
        nums.a = 6;
        nums.b = 6;

        IntPtr buffer1 = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(nums));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(nums, buffer1, false);
        mydef.sum = buffer1;

        int res = LibWrap.Initialize(ref mydef);

        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
}
```

With the above code, I am expecting '12' as output, but instead I am getting '-1504178328' as output.

I am a C# developer with no experience in C++ at all. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Your outer c# struct contains a pointer to the inner struct. The outer c++ struct contains the inner struct. That's the problem. My question is why the inner and outer structs at all. Why not pass `ref nums`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simpler P/Invoke wrapper:

```
public static class LibWrap
{
    [DllImport("C++.dll", EntryPoint = "initialize")]
    public static extern int Initialize(ref Nums nums);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Nums
    {
        public int a;
        public int b;
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
void CSharpExample()
{
    LibWrap.Nums nums;
    nums.a = 6;
    nums.b = 7;
    int res = LibWrap.Initialize(ref nums);
    Console.WriteLine(res);
}
```

In your example, you don't need any memory allocation and marshaling, because:

- `LibWrap.Nums` is a struct, thus local variable `nums` in `CSharpExample()` is allocated completely on stack.
- passing managed struct `LibWrap.Nums` by `ref` to `LibWrap.Initialize` will pass the pointer to local variable `nums` on stack.
- `LibWrap.Initialize` is called synchronously, so that the pointer you pass to it isn't used anywhere after `LibWrap.Initialize` function exits. This is important because the pointer becomes invalid as soon as `CSharpExample()` exits.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much for your time and assistance.

Comment: Good answer. When you say 'you don't need memory allocation and marshalling' would it not also be useful to say that the types used are blittable? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the C# side, you are not handling the nested struct correctly.  Try this instead:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct mynums {
    public int num1;
    public int num2;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct sum1 {
    public mynums nums;
}

public class LibWrap {
    [DllImport("C++.dll", EntryPoint = "initialize")]
    public static extern int Initialize(ref sum1 summing);
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        sum1 mysum;
        mysum.nums.num1 = 6;
        mysum.nums.num2 = 6;
        int res = LibWrap.Initialize(ref mysum);
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
}
```

That being said, having a struct whose sole data member is another struct is redundant and unnecessary. You should remove the outer struct altogether, eg:

```cpp
struct nums {
    int num1;
    int num2;
};

extern "C" {

__declspec(dllexport) int initialize(nums *summing) {
    return summing->num1 + summing->num2;
}

}
```

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct nums {
    public int num1;
    public int num2;
}

public class LibWrap {
    [DllImport("C++.dll", EntryPoint = "initialize")]
    public static extern int Initialize(ref nums summing);
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        nums mynums;
        mynums.num1 = 6;
        mynums.num2 = 6;
        int res = LibWrap.Initialize(ref mynums);
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you so much for your time and assistance. However, in my case, I cannot alter the code of C++ file.

Comment: @Uzair And yet the answer that you accepted shows code without the struct nesting....... It happens that the layout matches exactly, but semantically it is not a match, and future changes could lead to breakage and confusion.