# What is the equivalent of Type Statement from VBA in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, vba

What is the equivalent of [Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/type-statement) from VBA in C#?

I am asking, because I have some code in Excel which I am trying to turn into a standalone C# application. I have a function, which comes from a .dll, which takes in a Type with some strings and longs as an argument. How would I replicate this in C#? Will this even work, or the will the function from .dll not even work in C#?

I haven't yet experimented with this, because it is all connected to a working database, and I want to know how this would work before I mess something up.

Comment: What dll? Is it a managed .Net assembly?

Comment: Judging from linked Docs, that would be a class or struct. But I am suspicious if a C# implementation would be compatible with your "dll". But maybe (and probably)  there is a decent replacement on nuget ...

Comment: I believe you are looking for [struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/struct).

Comment: Thank you, I will try with struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that you use a `Type` in VBA to pass data to a function contained in some DLL. Seeing some code would help, but this technique is *usually* used to call a (Windows API or third-party) DLL expecting some C-type struct.

In C#, you would use [P/Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke) to call functions in unmanaged DLLs, and you would typically use a `struct` for complex types required by the DLL. Using a `class` is also possible, but there are [some subtleties to be aware of](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22823960/87698).

A simple example can be found in this SO answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47429104/87698

If your DLL is part of the Windows API, you can use http://pinvoke.net/ to find ready-to-use C# declarations for the functions as well as the data structures.

Answer (score 2):

The example in the linked documentation would be rewritten as:

```
struct StateData 
{
    int[] CityCode;
    string County;
}

var Washington = new StateData[100];
```

Although at some point you'd have to initialize CityCode. In VBA you could do it implicitly but in c# you'd have to write something like:

```
foreach (var w in Washington) w.CityCode = new int[100];
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest will be the [`Struct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/struct) datatype. It is similar in that it is a user-defined data type containing one or more elements (members) of various data types, and these elements are accessed as fields of the Type/Struct.
Both are values types and use stack allocation (usually).